# Показать ошибку нет интернета используя Retrofit 2 и RxJava

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rxjava2

для получения данных с сервера использую вот такой запрос:

```
   public void getContactDataTechnicalSupport(String country) {
         compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
         ApiFactory apiFactory = ApiFactory.getInstance();
         ApiService apiService = apiFactory.getApiService();

         Disposable disposable = apiService.getContactDataTechnicalSupport(country)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                if (response.getSuccess())
                    view.setTechSupportData(response);
                else
                    view.showErrorRequestSupportContact(response.getCode(), response.getMessage());
              }, throwable -> {
                    view.showErrorRequestSupportContact(0, "Ошибка подключения");
              });
          compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }
```

Мне нужно показать пользователю что у него нет интернета, данный запрос показывает это сообщение даже если ошибка на сервере, что не совсем корректно, как мне можно обработать ошибку чтобы показать сообщение?

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать пинг сервера гугла.

Comment: Возможно, надо проверить является ли ошибка `throwable` экземпляром класса `HttpException`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб К сожалению не помогло

Comment: Почему именно не помогло? Расскажите подробнее, иначе сложно предложить другие варианты. Сделаю обоснованное предположение - надо проверять на UnknownHostException - и в этом случае показывать сообщение о проблемах с сетевым соединением.

Answer (score 1):

Решил это вот так:

```
    apiService.getContactDataTechnicalSupport(country)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                if (response.getSuccess())
                    view.setTechSupportData(response);
                else
                    view.showErrorRequestSupportContact(response.getCode(), response.getMessage());
            }, throwable -> {
                if (throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException || throwable instanceof UnknownHostException)
                    view.showErrorRequestSupportContact(NO_INTERNET_CODE, "Нет интернета");
                else
                    view.showErrorRequestSupportContact(0, "Ошибка подключения");
            });
```